# Open String CSV data in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

So I currently have some CSV formatted data as a string in my JavaScript code as part of a chrome extension. What I need is a button which when clicked will open a new tab with that CSV data loaded in as a Google Sheets document. Basically a "Open in Google Sheets" button. The opened Google sheet document will preferably not be stored in the signed in user's drive (or any drive), but just open a new tab with the CSV file opened.

```
$("#opnWithSheetsBtn").click((e)=>{
    myCSV = $("#userInput").value()
    // Code which will open CSV data in new tab using Google Sheets
})
```

TLDR: I want to create a "Open with Google Sheets" button in a front-end application.

Comment: Yes. I'm not too familiar with the Google Drive API and I'm unsure if I should use the Sheets or Drive API. I also would prefer the .CSV file to not be stored in the users drive but just opened in Google Sheets, if possible the user doesn't have to even be logged into a Google account and can just see the data opened up in a new tab. I want to basically use the Google Sheets website to display data to the user.

Comment: Please improve your question to make it clear that you html is on a web site and not a web app.  Perhaps provide an example of what your code looks like and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have added some code @Cooper

Comment: So, if you don't want the user to have the sheet stored in his Drive where are you planning on storing it? On your/your application drive and then make it public?

Comment: The best case would be it just being opened in Google Sheets but not stored in anyone's drive (allowing users with no Google account to view the Google sheet). However, if that isn't possible without storing it in a drive then I would want it to be stored in the users drive.

Comment: Please share you current code and explain where this button you speak will be.

Comment: The button will be in the HTML with an ID of 'opnWithSheetsBtn'. The code in the question is the event listener which will get fired when the button is clicked. I capture the user input in the event listener and the next part is meant to open the new tab with Google sheets and the data. There is one HTML file and one JS file, HTML isn't that complicated just a button.

Answer (score 0):

> Taking into account the information that you shared my assumption is the following: you have your CSV data converted into a Javascript object and stringified. Correct me if I am wrong.

If my assumption is right, then, on the HTML button click you would need to run the function provided below. To be able to run this in Apps Scrip you must go to **Resources->Advanced Google Services** and activate the Sheets API service (as we will be using its method `batchUpdate`).

This Sheet API function will grant us with a better efficency than compared to using vanilla Apps Script.

```js
function insertCSVinNewSheet(data){

  // Use create to create a new Spreadsheet and get its first sheet. 
  var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.create('newSpreadSheet').getSheets()[0].getSheetId();
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  // Create the resource to update your sheet
  var resource = {
    requests: [
      {
        pasteData: {
          data: data,
          coordinate: { sheetId: sheetId },
          delimiter: ","
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  
  // Use the Sheet API to make a batch update in the new sheet inserting all our data
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
}
```